# Can I use a simple wood spacer for double glazed glass inserts in interior french door?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, glazing

I am building a home office and and want to modestly sound insulate the office from the living room. I want to make a custom pair of french doors with *two* sets of double glazed glass (1/2" spaced double glazed glass, 1.5" air gap, then a second 1/2" spaced double glazed glass).

This is an interior application, so humidity and moisture control are not going to be an issue.

Do I still need to use double sealed aluminum spacers, or can some simple wood spacers with a bit of window glazing suffice?